# Month Picker in VF page with Lightning Classes support

Tags: visualforce, lightning-design-system

I have a requirement to add month picker(not date) in a VF page. VF page is using SLDS for CSS. 
Any plugin that could provide support for both would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

### Apex

One option would be to use a picklist and reference it in Visualforce and Apex.

For instance, given you say you're using SLDS, you can simply use:

```
<div class="slds-form-element slds-size_1-of-1">
  <apex:outputLabel styleClass="slds-form-element__label" for="field" value="Label" />
  <apex:selectList id="field" styleClass="slds-select" value="{!selectedOption}" size="1">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!selectList}"/>
  </apex:selectList>
</div>
```

The important parts here are that you're using SLDS and usual Visualforce Helpers to generate your List.

The list will contain whatever is in `selectList` and the value will be assigned to `selectedOption` to be used in SOQL, for example.

Your Apex would look like below:

```
public String selectedOption { get; set; }

public List<SelectOption> GetSelectList() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

      options = new List<String>();
      Schema.DescribeFieldResult field = My_Object__c.My_Picklist__c.getDescribe();

      for (Schema.PicklistEntry f : field.getPicklistValues()) {
        options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getLabel()));
      }

      return options;
    }
}
```

`selectedOption` will just store the selected option. `GetSelectList()` will return the picklist values on the object `My_Object__c` on the field `My_Picklist__c`.

SLDS is literally just a CSS framework so can be integrated even with standard Visualforce Helpers in most cases I've come across.

### JQuery

If you'd prefer to use JavaScript and are using jQuery and jQueryUI, you could use the below to create a DatePicker using their functionality. Something like below would work:

```
$(function() {
  $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: false,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'MM',
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedMonth, 1));
    }
  });
});
```

Then your HTML would just need to be where you add the class `date-picker` to your field:

```
<div class="slds-form-element slds-size_1-of-1">
  <apex:outputLabel styleClass="slds-form-element__label" for="field" value="Field" />
  <apex:inputText id="field" styleClass="slds-input date-picker" value="{!selectedOption}" />
</div>
```

You're still using standard Visualforce Helpers, just displaying things a bit differently.

Comment: That is the issue. I cannot use select lists. Client wants it as the datepicker in lightning